# %prec doesn't seem to work?

Tags: bison

Here is a sample of my y file.

```
| rval '<' rval
| rval '<' '<' rval
| rval '>' rval
| rval '>' '>' rval

| rval LSHIFT rval
| rval RSHIFT rval
```

I'd like to allow < < and > > to work like << and >>. I thought they would be difficult but found "Context-Dependent Precedence"
http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Contextual-Precedence.html

However it doesnt seem to work. Writing
    | rval '<' '<' rval %prec LSHIFT

seems to do nothing. I tried putting it here where * = "%prec LSHIFT" except i only had one at a time

```
| * rval * '<' * '<' * rval  *
```

Every slot didnt seem to work. I didnt notice any warnings except when I had more than one %prec LSHIFT in a rule.

How do I get bison to treat > > and << as >> and <<. Note: I can't make rshift >\s*> in the lexer because that would interfere with other things

Comment: It's not very fair to ask the same question at multiple places, http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bison/2013-03/msg00000.html.

Comment: @akim: Why not? I like posting on both. Mailing seems the best place but most people (including myself) search on SO first.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in the parser (without `%glr-parser`), as it would require two tokens of lookahead.  The problem is that the "precedence rules" aren't really doing precedence resolution.  They're just a hack to resolve shift/reduce conflicts in favor of one token over another.  In this case the relevant comparison is between the token inside the left `rval` and the `'<'` or `'>'` token.  The parser needs to compare these to determine whether to reduce whatever rule is "inside" that `rval`, or whether to shift.  Without more lookahead it has no idea whether the `'<'` is followed by another `'<'` or something else.